# Making Reads and Writes in Scala Play for lists of custom classes

Tags: json, scala, playframework

So I have two classes in my project

```
case class Item(id: Int, name: String)
```

and

```
case class Order(id: Int, items: List[Item])
```

I'm trying to make reads and writes properties for Order but I get a compiler error saying:

"No unapply or unapplySeq function found"

In my controller I have the following:

```
implicit val itemReads = Json.reads[Item]
implicit val itemWrites = Json.writes[Item]
implicit val listItemReads = Json.reads[List[Item]]
implicit val listItemWrites = Json.writes[List[Item]]
```

The code works for `itemReads` and `itemWrites` but not for the bottom two. Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong, I'm new to Play framework.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "`No unapply or unapplySeq function found`" error is caused by these two:

```
implicit val listItemReads = Json.reads[List[Item]]
implicit val listItemWrites = Json.writes[List[Item]]
```

Just throw them away. [As Ende said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34437954/56285), Play knows how to deal with lists.

But you need `Reads` and `Writes` for `Order` too! And since you do both reading and writing, it's simplest to define a [`Format`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaJsonCombinators#Format), a mix of the `Reads` and `Writes` traits. This should work:

```
case class Item(id: Int, name: String)

object Item {
  implicit val format = Json.format[Item]
}

case class Order(id: Int, items: List[Item])

object Order {
  implicit val format = Json.format[Order]
}
```

Above, the [ordering is significant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34616376/56285); `Item` and the companion object must come before `Order`.

So, once you have all the implicit converters needed, the key is to *make them properly visible* in the controllers. The above is one solution,  but there are other ways, as I learned after [trying to do something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34615571/56285).

Answer (score 9):

You don't actually need to define those two implicits, play already knows how to deal with a list:

```
scala> import play.api.libs.json._ 
import play.api.libs.json._

scala>   case class Item(id: Int, name: String)
defined class Item

scala>   case class Order(id: Int, items: List[Item])
defined class Order

scala>   implicit val itemReads = Json.reads[Item]
itemReads: play.api.libs.json.Reads[Item] = play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anon$8@478fdbc9

scala>   implicit val itemWrites = Json.writes[Item]
itemWrites: play.api.libs.json.OWrites[Item] = play.api.libs.json.OWrites$$anon$2@26de09b8

scala>   Json.toJson(List(Item(1, ""), Item(2, "")))
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = [{"id":1,"name":""},{"id":2,"name":""}]

scala>   Json.toJson(Order(10, List(Item(1, ""), Item(2, ""))))
res1: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"id":10,"items":[{"id":1,"name":""},{"id":2,"name":""}]}
```

The error you see probably happens because play uses the unapply method to construct the macro expansion for your read/write and `List` is an abstract class, play-json needs concrete type to make the macro work.

Comment: You are right in that `Json.reads[List[Item]]` and `Json.writes[List[Item]]` are not necessary; those cause the "No unapply or unapplySeq function found" error. However, `List` works just fine, no concrete type needed. I think OP's case can be solved by making the implicit converters properly visible, using one of the approaches here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34615571/56285

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
case class Item(id: Int, name: String)

case class Order(id: Int, items: List[Item])

implicit val itemFormat = Json.format[Item]
implicit val orderFormat: Format[Order] = (
  (JsPath \ "id").format[Int] and
    (JsPath \ "items").format[JsArray].inmap(
      (v: JsArray) => v.value.map(v => v.as[Item]).toList,
      (l: List[Item]) => JsArray(l.map(item => Json.toJson(item)))
    )
  )(Order.apply, unlift(Order.unapply))
```

This also allows you to customize the naming for your JSON object. Below is an example of the serialization in action.

```
Json.toJson(Order(1, List(Item(2, "Item 2"))))
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"id":1,"items":[{"id":2,"name":"Item 2"}]}

Json.parse(
  """
    |{"id":1,"items":[{"id":2,"name":"Item 2"}]}
  """.stripMargin).as[Order]
res1: Order = Order(1,List(Item(2,Item 2)))
```

I'd also recommend using `format` instead of `read` and `write` if you are doing symmetrical serialization / deserialization.

Comment: @Will: while this works, it is *way* more complicated than necessary, fortunately! As Ende pointed out, Play already knows how to deal with lists. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34618829/56285