# scala request.body.asJson access Array

Tags: arrays, json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

in my play Framework app I send an json to backend, in backend I want to access on array in the json

I tried this:

```
val processSteps = request.body.asJson.map{
  json => (json \ "stepsData").asOpt[Object].map { steps =>
    println(steps)
}

for (processStep <- steps) {

  processStep.map(_.validate[ProcessStepTemplatesModel] match {
```

stepsData is an array I want to access

Request:

```
Some({"steps":"","stepsData":[{"steptitle":"sd","title":"asd"}],"stepType":"duty","createdat":"2017-05-31 14:30:26","updatedat":"2017-05-31 14:30:26","activeSnackbar":false,"snackbarText":{"type":"span","key":null,"ref":null,"props":{"children":[{"key":null,"re
f":null,"props":{"value":"snackbar.processes.createProcess"},"_owner":null,"_store":{}},": ",null]},"_owner":null,"_store":{}},"approvedProcessTemplates":[],"approveprocess":17,"approveprocessTitle":"Felix","trainingsprocess":47,"trainprocessTitle":"Posaune","d
eleted":false,"dialogActive":false,"title":"ads","processtemplate":1,"loaded":true,"version":"asd","responsible":"asd","accountable":"asd","consulted":"asd","informed":"asd","deadline":"2017-05-18T12:30:09.460Z","dialogActions":[{"label":{"key":null,"ref":null,
"props":{"value":"dialog.processes.deleteProcess.cancel"},"_owner":null,"_store":{}}}],"dialogTitle":{"key":null,"ref":null,"props":{"value":"dialog.processes.selectProcessTemplate.trainingsprocess.header"},"_owner":null,"_store":{}},"dialogHandlerVariable":1})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you show me how your data looks like?

The way I would approach this is, have a case class for stepsData :

```
case class StepData(attributes ..)
```

And then have a wrapper :

```
case class StepDataWrapper(stepsData : List[StepData])
```

Then specify an implicit format in your controller :

```
import play.api.libs.json._

implicit val stepDataFormat = Json.format[StepData]

implicit val stepDataListWrapperFormat =Json.format[StepDataWrapper]
```

And then,

```
  val processSteps = request.body.asJson.asOpt[StepDataWrapper]
                     .map{ 
                     stepDataWrapper => stepDataWrapper.stepsData.map(println(_))
                     }
```

Comment: added the request above

Comment: defined this case class : StepData(steptitle : String, title : String)

and follow the rest as above, it should work.

Comment: Maybe following this can help you out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34437520/making-reads-and-writes-in-scala-play-for-lists-of-custom-classes

Answer (score 1):

You should do this in json validation, that is in your `asOpt` method:

```
(json \ "stepsData").asOpt[Array[ProcessStepTemplatesModel]]
```

If you're using other fields in the body, you could even define a case class for expected body, and validate it directly:

```
case class StepProcessingRequestData(
  stepsData: Array[ProcessStempTemplatesModel],
  ... // add your other fields, as defined in your JSON schema
)

object StepProcessingRequestData {
  implicit val reads = Json.reads[StepProcessingRequestData]
}

val processStepsOpt: Option[StepProcessingRequestData] = 
  request.body.asJson.flatMap(_.asOpt[StepProcessingRequestData])
```

Comment: first one returns nothing, second lots of errors ;)

Comment: What kind of errors? Do you have an implicit `Reads[StepProcessingRequestData]` in scope? does it validate the elements in your array?